# Prove that when $|H| = \infty$, $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle$ and $\langle x^m \rangle = \langle x^{|m|} \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I want to prove Theorem 7(2) in section 2.3 from *Abstract Algebra 3rd Edition* by Dummit & Foote. This theorem states:

> Let $H = \langle x \rangle$ be a cyclic group. If $|H| = \infty$, then for any distinct nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$, $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle$. Furthermore, for every integer $m$, $\langle x^m \rangle = \langle x^{|m|} \rangle$, where $|m|$ denotes the absolute value of $|m|$, so that nontrivial subgroups of $H$ correspond bijectively with the integers $1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

This is my attempt at the proof, but I don't think it is rigorous enough. I feel like I am missing something.

Suppose $|H| = \infty$ and $\langle x^a \rangle = \langle x^b \rangle$ for distinct nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$. According to Prop. 2(2), this implies $x^a \neq x^b$. And $|H| = \infty$ implies that $x^a$ and $x^b$ are distinct, so $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle$. We also have $\langle x^m \rangle = \langle x^{|m|} \rangle$, since for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\langle x^m \rangle = \langle x^{-m} \rangle$.

The Prop. 2(2) referenced in the proof is:

> If $|H| = \infty$, then $x^n \neq 1$ for all $n \neq 0$ and $x^a \neq x^b$ for all $a \neq b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You still haven’t shown why $x^a \neq x^b$ implies $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle$ - which is in general not true as the second part tells you, so you need to use the non-negativity assumption.

Comment: Hint: what exactly are elements of $\langle x^a \rangle$? What powers of $x$ are these elements? So if $\langle x^a \rangle = \langle x^b \rangle$, what does that tell you (using Prop. 2(2)) about the relation between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $\langle x^a \rangle = \{x^{ak} | k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, so that means $b\ell = a$ for some $\ell$. And according to Prop. 2(2), since $|H| = \infty$, we $x^a \neq x^b$. So $b$ divides $a$ but is not equal to $a$ ($\ell \neq 1$).

Comment: Indeed, $bl = a$ for some integer $l$, but you would also get $ak = b$ for some integer $k$, right? So then $a = bl = akl$. Either $a = 0$, in which case you already have $b = ak = 0$ as well, or $kl = 1$ - then what is $k$ and $l$?

Comment: Your *Suppose...* paragraph is repetitive: two sentences in a row you say that $|H|=\infty$ implies $x^a \ne x^b$. And after that implication the paragraph has a big logical hole: with no further justification you simply jump to the conclusion $\langle x^a \rangle \ne \langle x^b \rangle$ (which, as said by @DavidGao, cannot be deduced from $x^a \ne x^b$).

Comment: @DavidGao Then $k$ and $l$ are either both $1$ or $-1$. If $k$ & $l$ are both equal to $1$, then $a = b$. If $k$ & $l$ are both equal to $-1$, then $-a = b$. But this can't happen since $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, unless if both are zero. So in every case, $a = b$ implies $x^a = x^b$.

Comment: @Nudibranch Your conclusion is a bit off. We have begun with $\langle x^a \rangle = \langle x^b \rangle$ and ended with $a = b$. The contrapositive of this statement is exactly what you want, that is, if $a, b$ are distinct nonnegative integers, then $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle$.

Comment: @DavidGao Sorry I didn't add that, I realized it was the contrapositive. So $\langle x^a \rangle = \langle x^b \rangle \implies x^a = x^b$ implies $\langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^b \rangle \implies x^a \neq x^b$ for distinct nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Technically we ended with $a = b$ instead of $x^a = x^b$ - though this doesn’t matter too much. But the contrapositive is the other way around - the contrapositive is $a \neq b \Rightarrow \langle x^a \rangle \neq \langle x^a \rangle$, assuming $a, b$ are nonnegative integers.